# Accessing all properties from child tables by innerjoin to use on asp:GridView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, gridview

I wrote this method to use it as SelectMethod in asp GridView. I want to access all the properties in child tables(EmployeeCourses ,EmployeeLanguages ,EmployeeSkills ) as well,but I cannot select y , z , w in the query as their type mismatch. 
What option do I have here?

```
 public List<EmployementRequest> requestsGrid_GetData()
    {
        var ukn = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities();
        var query = (from x in ukn.EmployementRequests
            join y in ukn.EmployeeCourses on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals y.FKEmployementRequest
            join z in ukn.EmployeeLanguages on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals z.FKEmploymentRequest
            join w in ukn.EmployeeSkills on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals w.FKEmploymentRequest
            select x).ToList();

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an anonymous type or a custom class(DTO) to save your projection, in your case should be a DTO because you want to return the result, so you need to define a class with 4 properties to save those entities:

```
public class EmployementDTO
{
  //Define properties here
  public EmployementRequest EmployementRequest{get;set;}
  //..
}
```

And then:

```
public List<EmployementDTO> requestsGrid_GetData()
{
    var ukn = new UKN_DBNAMEEntities();
    var query = (from x in ukn.EmployementRequests
        join y in ukn.EmployeeCourses on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals y.FKEmployementRequest
        join z in ukn.EmployeeLanguages on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals z.FKEmploymentRequest
        join w in ukn.EmployeeSkills on x.PKEmploymentRequest equals w.FKEmploymentRequest
        select new EmployementDTO{EmployementRequest=x,EmployeeCourse=y,...);

    return query.ToList();
}
```